# Audio Playing on Headphones and Speakers (Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 15.04, headphones

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 15.04. The upgrade went fine, except that now audio plays from the headphones and the speaker at the same time.

My speakers are plugged into the motherboard's green audio jack while the headphone jack is integrated into the front of my computer case. In the sound settings, there are 3 channels: Digital Output, Headphones, and Line Out. However, changing the audio on either Headphones or Line Out affects both the speaker volume and the headphone volume.

On Ubuntu 14.04, the channels had been Headphones, Digital Output, and Analog Output. Changing Analog Output did not affect Headphones and vice versa. Additionally, when I plugged in headphones, it automatically muted the speakers.

I am running on AMD hardware. Gigabyte GA 970a-DS3P, AMD FX-6300, Sapphire Radeon R7 240. The audio is built into the motherboard.

One difference is that I installed Ubuntu 15.04 in UEFI mode, whereas I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 in BIOS compatibility mode.

Additionally, because of a quirk in the motherboard, I turned off IOMMU in the BIOS settings. However, I did this in both 15.04 and 14.04, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, and also a GA-970A-DS3P, but I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 (IOMMU is off, but I didn't turn it off myself: it was already off when I got the PC). So I'm a bit surprised that it worked for you in 14.04.
What kernel version were you using? I'm on 3.16.0-37.

Comment: For the record, I filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1457476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
sudo echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" \
   >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and reboot your PC.
For improving the out-of-the-box experience in Ubuntu, I filed [bug 1457476](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1457476), let's hope that this can be fixed once and for all.

Comment: Works greatly. And I'm not using a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Alsa mixer and turning down the device that you're  not using

Just type alsamixer in a terminal, hope this helps

Comment: This actually works, but I'd really like automute to work. That is, whenever I plug in headphones, the speakers are automatically muted.

Comment: Some speakers have a headphone jack built into it try using that one instead.

Comment: "automute" is a switch to activate in alsamixer (at least on my pc )